# How to implement facebook send, twitter share, send sms, send email in my phonegap android application?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

As i am using HTML based phonegap framework, i need a plugin to implement this. when i searched over google, i got two revelent searches.

1. http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/android-phonegap-plugin-for-social-share-email-facebook-twitter-and-sms

   a. In the above twitter functionality is not implemented.

   b. There is a typo in the above facebook share code 
   window.plugins.SendSms.social ----> (should be)window.plugins.ShareSocial.social

   c. As it is developed for phonegap 1.9, it has some deprecated methods to be used in the version phonegap 2.1.0,

   ctx.startActivity() ----> cordova.getActivity().startActivity() 
   this.ctx.startActivityForResult ----> this.cordova.startActivityForResult
   com.phonegap ----> org.apache.cordova

   I have done all the above updates, now all my errors are gone but still nothing is happening when i click on the    buttons email, sms, facebook( i correctly implemented the javascript click events for these buttons)

   Can anyone who knows java,phonegap plugin dev and javascript, Please implement the same plugin for 2.1.0 post sample    code to show how it is working.I need it badly ASAP.
2. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share

   There is no single example on how to use this plugin for my purpose. Even the official documentation is not helpfull.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411789/android-phonegap-version-2-0-or-higher-any-update-for-share-plugin-for-facebook

for proper solution.

Comment: facebook is not working rest all working...please need your help

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the same plugin for Cordova 2  Could you please try that and let me know if you still have the issue. http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/social-share-plugin-for-android-cordova-2-2-0-email-sms-facebook-twitter-share

Comment: WILL,THIS NOT WORK FOR **cordova-2.1.0**?? because `I am getting this Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:985`

Comment: does this  plugin directly go to the FB???? because for me it just opened all the available options of sharing.

Comment: Regarding FB, It will show you the options to share the url. Otherwise you have to use Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Really a cool and usefull plugin! I had to make just two edit to make it work... 
First: change  window.plugins.ShareSocial.sms in window.SocialShare.sms (for all the sharer)

Second: change SocialShare.prototype.sms in SocialShare.sms in social.js file

Now i have a question: can you give me any suggestion to add a share to twitter method?

Comment: This is referred to Sarath DR response and plugin

Comment: errors i am facing,inspite of the changes done..
**1** `05-31 17:29:26.020: E/Web Console(8807): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null:18` **line no:18** `document.querySelector("#sendSms").addEventListener("touchstart", function()`....**2** `05-31 17:29:26.150: E/Web Console(8807): Uncaught ReferenceError: SocialShare is not defined:15
05-31 17:29:38.745: V/webview(8807):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE ` **line no 15** `window.SocialShare = new SocialShare();`

Comment: **3** ontouching the fb button on screen `05-31 17:29:39.165: E/Web Console(8807): Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function:76` **line no 76** is the html code for the button. **PLEASE HELP !!!**

Comment: WILL,THIS NOT WORK FOR **cordova-2.1.0**?? because `I am getting this Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:985`

Comment: does this  plugin directly go to the FB???? because for me it just opened all the available options of sharing.